# Why std::istream_iterator ignores newline characters?

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::stringstream str; str << "abc\ndef";

    std::cout << "[" << str.str() << "]" << std::endl;

    std::istream_iterator<char> it(str), end;

    for (; it != end; ++it)
    {
        std::cout << "[" << unsigned(*it) << "]";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
[abc
def]
[97][98][99][100][101][102]
```

Why std::istream_iterator ignored the new-line character?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `istream_iterator` uses `operator>>`. And `istream::operator>>(char)` skips whitespace, unless you unset the `skipws` flag of the stream. (e.g. using [`noskipws`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws))

It's the same output you would get if you did this:

```
char c;
while (str >> c)
    std::cout << "[" << unsigned(c) << "]";
```

Answer (score 5):

You can disable skipping any whitespace in the input by changing a little bit of your code:

```
std::stringstream str; str << std::noskipws << "abc\ndef";
```

New output:

```
[abc
def]
[97][98][99][10][100][101][102]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` instead, it won't loss spaces and newlines.