# Need for noskipws on stream with T=unsigned char in binary mode?

Tags: c++, file-io, stream, binaryfiles

I came across [Reading the binary file into the vector of unsigned chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138353/reading-the-binary-file-into-the-vector-of-unsigned-chars/21802936) and tested the code discussed in the question.

The code of interest is below:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);
file.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);

std::vector<BYTE> vec;
vec.insert(vec.begin(),
           std::istream_iterator<BYTE>(file),
           std::istream_iterator<BYTE>());
```

According to Benjamin Lindley's answer at [Why std::istream_iterator ignores newline characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268212/why-stdistream-iterator-ignores-newline-characters), `istream::operator>>(char)` skips white spaces. But the type above is `unsigned char`, and the file was opened with `std::binary`.

Why did the code require an explicit call to `file.unsetf(std::ios::skipws)` (or alternately, `file >> std::noskipws)`?

Comment: `ios::binary` just makes it not convert newline characters. Also note that `char` may be the same type as `unsigned char`.

Comment: The `std::ios_base::binary` openmode doesn't disable the "formatting" functionality of `operator>>()`. It only suppresses system-specific conversions.

Comment: 0x499602D2 and user3286380 - so `std::binary` on a stream still has the notion of a `line` (as in `getline` and `readline`)?

Comment: You may want to [`std::istreambuf_iterator<char>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istreambuf_iterator) instead of `std::istream_iterator<BYTE>` if you're trying to do what I think you are. And your performance will likely be better in the process of doing so.

Comment: Thanks  WhozCraig. I'm not sure what the difference is (or why an octet even has a character trait). What I really wanted was `std::begin(file)` and `std::end(file)`. But that would have been too easy.

Comment: may be this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253864/skipws-flag-set-when-opening-an-input-file-stream-in-binary-mode

Comment: @noloader It works because `std::istreambuf_iterator` works directly on the buffer, which performs *unformatted* extraction (meaning whitespace is also extracted).

Comment: You could also just do `vec.assign(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());`.

Comment: Thanks 0x499602D2. `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` is the wrong type. It would probably make the veins in Bjourne's neck bulge.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. How is it the wrong *type*?

Comment: 0x499602D2 - I'm operating on `unsigned chars` or octets. It's binary data in the customary sense (not the C++ sense). I'm not operating on `chars` with traits like white space, new line, etc. They are different types.

Comment: @0x499602D2 - when I check the outtput of `cpp -dM < /dev/null | grep char`, I see `char` is signed: `#define __INT8_TYPE__ char`. I'm fairly certain these are different types on this system (Mac OS X 10.8.3).

Answer (score 2):

The basic algorithm for >> of a string is:

> 1) skip whitespace
>   2) read and extract until next whitespace

If you use `noskipws`, then the `first step is skipped`.

After the first read, you are positionned on a whitespace, so the next (and all following) reads will stop immediatly, extracting nothing.

Comment: Thanks anon. There is no `string` (or its primitive, the `char`). Perhaps I'm using the wrong classes for this exercise.